# Is it possible to move my domain from one.com to cloudflare

Tags: dns, cloudflare

Is it possible to move my domain from one.com to cloudflare?

If so, can I then buy an ssl from them?

Also, any resources on how to do this would be great.

My biggest concern is the downtime when switching over.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare is not a webhost and domain registrar services are only available to Enterprise customers.  It provides DNS, proxy, CDN and various other tools.

SSL is provided free to all customers on all plans, but your certificate will be shared.  If you need/desire a [dedicated certificate](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/dedicated-certificates/) that can be purchased as an add-on to any account for $5 a month.

If you are worried about downtime when you begin routing your traffic through Cloudflare (assuming that's what you mean by "move" to) just make sure you follow [steps 1 and 2 of the Cloudflare 101 tutorials](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200820158-Cloudflare-101) in the Knowledge Base before changing your nameservers in Step 3.  It should be seamless.

A little more detail to answer the follow-up:

After adding your domain to Cloudflare, and setting up your DNS records, you will be provided with details for two Cloudflare nameservers. Take them to your registrar (in this case one.com) and update your nameserver information. As soon as the changes take effect with your registrar your traffic will begin routing through Cloudflare which is waiting and ready to go.

Comment: I think I need to point my one.com name server to a new one that i need to create on cloudflare?

Comment: Actually Cloudflare *is* a domain registrar, but this is off topic here anyway

Answer (score 0):

One.com is shared hosting and you can not change DNS settings on it aside from creating new subdomains. Also, your shared host will change its IP pretty frequently, so pointing a non-one.com managed domain to your one webspace's IP will break faster than you can update it. There is a reason that you can't even see your IP in your account settings.

If you really want to use cloudflare for DDoS protection and its other benefits, one.com and most other shared hosting is not a good choice.

When you search for a new web&domain host, confirm that they allow you to move your DNS to cloudflare before you sign up.